# Powershell WPF use textbox input as a command

Tags: wpf, azure, powershell, command-line-interface

Working on a project that users azcli. When I hardcode a command in a WPF textbox, the command runs and returns the desired results in my output textbox.

However, when I try to take user typed input from the textbox, nothing happens. I don't get any errors but I also do not get the results. At best I can get the output textbox to simply display the text I entered into the input textbox

The following code works and as noted in my comment in the code, hardcoding the command produces the desired result.

```
function run {
    
#This runs the command and produces the desired result when I click "RunButton"
    $cmdOutput = (az ad user list 2>&1)
    $cmdOutput
    $outputBox.text = $cmdOutput
}

$LoginButton.add_click({login})
$RunButton.add_click({run})

$xamlForm.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

When I try to use the following "Run" function with the "az ad user list" cmdlet in the RunBox however, rather than hardcoding it in the variable, my output box simply displays (az ad user list 2>&1)

```
function run {

    $runInput = "(" + $RunBox.Text + " 2>&1)"
    $runOutput = $runInput
    $runOutput
    $outputBox.text = $runOutput
}
```

I've also tried it with $Runbox.Value.Text to no avail.

Bonus question, I'm positive I messed up my StatusBox try/catch. It always simply updates to connected once I click Login.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: You're looking for [`Invoke-Expression "$($RunBox.Text) 2>&1"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you nailed it, thanks so much!

Comment: For your try/catch, it won't trip to the catch block except on terminating errors. Your login failures are gracefully failing. What might be more useful is to check `$LASTEXITCODE` to see if it is greater than zero rather than try/catch there.

Comment: Are any precautions take to ensure that the user does not enter a destructive command? This would seem to be a significant security risk.

Comment: @lit my assumption here is that OP is just providing a local makeshift GUI for his az cli scripts - but if the input is to be passed off elsewhere you obviously want to make sure consumers don't treat it as trusted

Comment: I'd like to second lit's comment. Accepting user input and blindly executing commands that they type in is highly unadvisable. It's convenient, but it is dangerous. Like driving a car. It's nice to be able to just drive to the store, but you could run over pedestrians while you do it very easily. This is why we test and require people to be licensed to drive. You're giving people a vehicle that can cause considerable damage, no license required. Want to run `remove-item $env:windir -recurse -force` as your command? Sure! Go ahead and delete the Windows folder...

Comment: Its no more of a security risk than running the commands in powershell with azcli itself.

@MathiasR.Jessen is correct in that this is tooling intended for myself and other azure certified engineers on my team. Account permissions in place on the users azure ad account will limit those users from running commands which they are not authorized to run.

TheMadTechnician, whats stopping those folks from running those commands on powershell anyhow?

For now, I am the only person who will be using this, and it will not be provided to folks who don't know any better.... I hope xD

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `@Mathias R. Jessen` for the comment. I do agree and  have followed the same way, check the below **`script`** :

```
$rithreader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create([System.IO.StringReader]::new($xaml))
$rithwin = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($rithreader)

function RithwikTest {
    $test = $rithwin.FindName("RunBox").Text
    try {
        $testout = Invoke-Expression -Command $test 2>&1
        $rithwin.FindName("OutputBox").Text = $testout
    } catch {
        $rithwin.FindName("OutputBox").Text = "Hello Rithwik Bojja , Error occurred: $_"
    }
}
$rithwin.FindName("RunButton").add_Click({RithwikTest})
$rithwin.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

<kbd>**`Output:`**</kbd>

[image]

Yes `@TheMadTechnician` it is risky, it is only suggested for single or local user.